# why jquery mobile leave some space in a list view of items only in portrait resolution

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile

whenever my list is small the jquery leave some white space after few theme space it happens only in portrait orientation in the IPAD and works fine in landscape and portrait  mode in browser and landscape mode in IPAD
here is a sample of one page-role my portrait resolution is 768 X 1024

```
<div data-role="page" id="videos" data-theme="e">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="videos.css" /><!-- my custom css -->

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="e"><!-- header -->
        <div class="ui-grid-b center-align">
            <div class="ui-block-a classBlock pad" data-class="1">
                <a data-rel="external" data-ajax="false" href="./FingerTips/index.html"  data-role="button" class="revise-menus">Collection</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b classBlock" data-class="2">
                <div class="titles">Store</div>
                <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
                    <a href="#booksnsubjects" data-role="button" >Books</a>
                    <a href="#appview" data-role="button" >Apps</a>
                    <a href="#videos" data-role="button" data-rel="external" data-theme="d">Video</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c classBlock" data-class="1">
                <img src="images/cart.png" id="linkcart">
                <div  id="cart-item"></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /grid-b -->  
    </div>      
    <div data-role="content"><!-- content -->
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" id="class-lists">
            <li><a data-class="IV" href="#subjects" data-transition="slide">VI</a></li>
            <li><a data-class="IIV" href="#subjects" data-transition="slide">VII</a></li>
            <li><a data-class="IIIV" href="#subjects" data-transition="slide">VIII</a></li>
            <li><a data-class="IX" href="#subjects" data-transition="slide">IX</a></li>
            <li><a data-class="X" href="#subjects" data-transition="slide">X</a></li>
            <li><a data-class="XI" href="#subjects" data-transition="slide">XI</a></li>
            <li><a data-class="XII" href="#subjects" data-transition="slide">XII</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- content -->      
 </div><!-- /page -->
```

please help me out of it is i am doing something wrong

Comment: Did you try using data-inset="true" with the listview? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

i found solution: using new version of jquery mobile JS solves the issue